# Angular 2 (RC 1): Data view not refreshing when data loaded from a file

Tags: angular

I have been attempting to display data in my view that is uploaded from a file. According to what I have read in the Angular documentation and online, using change detection should be how I accomplish refreshing part of a page when my data is updated and that change is not reflected in my view.

I am using a interface to define my data in translations.ts:

```
export interface ITranslation {
    siteName: string;
    pageName: string;
    languageCode: string;    
    englishCaption: string;
    translatedCaption: string;
    arrayIndex?: number;
}
```

I am using this type script code to perform the import and html template to display it:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CanDeactivate, ComponentInstruction, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { ITranslation } from './translation';

declare var Papa: any;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/translator-page-data-import.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/translator-page-data-import.component.css',
                'app/assets/css/ngmes.css',
                'app/assets/css/toastr.min.css',
                'app/assets/css/ui-grid.min.css',
                'app/assets/css/ui-grid-override.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    selector:'table',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class TranslatorPageDataImportComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Page Data Import';
   
    hasData: boolean = false;
    
    translations: ITranslation[] = [{
            "siteName": "none",
            "pageName": "none",
            "languageCode": "none",    
            "englishCaption": "none",
            "translatedCaption": "none"
        }];
    
    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }
    
    onChanges(changes){
         console.log("onChanges was fired");
    }
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('PAGE "' + this.pageTitle + '" WAS LOADED!!!');
    }
    
    importFile(evt) {
  let fileInput = evt.target;

        let file = fileInput.files[0];
        let textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                let incomingCsvData: string = reader.result;
                // turn on if you need to inspect the raw CSV data
                // console.log("Incoming CSV Data" + incomingCsvData);

                let newJsonData: any = Papa.parse(incomingCsvData, {header: true});
                // turn on if you need to see the converted CSV data
                //console.log("Incoming CSV Data converted to JSON: ");
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(newJsonData));
                
                if (newJsonData.errors.length == 0 ) {
                    this.translations = newJsonData.data;
                    console.log("Translations data was populated from file: ")
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.translations));
                                        
                    for (var i = 0; i < this.translations.length; i++) {
                        this.translations.arrayIndex = i;
                    }

                    this.translations.push({
                        "siteName": "none",
                        "pageName": "none",
                        "languageCode": "none",    
                        "englishCaption": "none",
                        "translatedCaption": "none"
                    });

                    this.hasData = true;
                    console.log("hasData is " + this.hasData);
                }
                else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < newJsonData.errors.length; i++) {
                        console.log("There were errors Importing the data.");
                        console.log("Error Type: " + newJsonData[i].errors.type);
                        console.log("Error Code: " + newJsonData[i].errors.code);
                        console.log("Error Message: " + newJsonData[i].errors.message);
                        console.log("Error Row: " + newJsonData[i].errors.row);
                    }
                }

            }

            reader.readAsText(file); 
        } else {
            console.log("File not supported!");
        }
     }     
}
```

```html
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class="page-title">
        <h3>{{pageTitle}}</h3>
    </div>
         
    <div class='page-body'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class="form-group required">
                <div class='col-md-3'>
                    <input type="file" id="fileInput" (change)='importFile($event)'>
                </div>                 
                <div class='col-md-3'>

                </div>                 
                <div class='col-md-3'>

                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3'>
             
                </div>                                
            </div>                
        </div>
         <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-12' id="newTranslationsRow">
                <div [ngSwitch]="hasData">
                    <div *ngSwitchWhen="true">
                        <h1>Data was imported</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchWhen="false">
                        <h1>No data was imported</h1>
                    </div>      
                    <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                        <h1>No data was imported</h1>
                    </div>                                   
                </div>
                <div class='table-responsive' id="translationsTable"  *ngIf='translations && translations.length'>
                    <table class='table'>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Application Name</th>
                                <th>Page Name</th>
                                <th>Language-Country Code</th>
                                <th>English Caption</th>
                                <th>Translated Caption</th>
                             </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr *ngFor='let translation of translations'>
                                <td>{{ translation.siteName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ translation.pageName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ translation.languageCode }}</td>
                                <td>{{ translation.englishCaption }}</td>
                                <td>{{ translation.translatedCaption }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my console log output that shows the data in the underlying JSON data array: 

`Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
translator-page-data-import.component.ts:43 PAGE "Page Data Import" WAS LOADED!!!
translator-page-data-import.component.ts:95 Translations data was populated from file: 
translator-page-data-import.component.ts:96 [{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Active","arrayIndex":"0"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"Add","arrayIndex":"1"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Cancel","arrayIndex":"2"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"Delete","arrayIndex":"3"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Load","arrayIndex":"4"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Okay","arrayIndex":"5"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"Save","arrayIndex":"6"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Activo","arrayIndex":"7"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"A?adir","arrayIndex":"8"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Cancelar","arrayIndex":"9"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"Borrar","arrayIndex":"10"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Carga","arrayIndex":"11"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Bueno","arrayIndex":"12"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"Salvar","arrayIndex":"13"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Aktiv","arrayIndex":"14"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"Hinzuf?gen","arrayIndex":"15"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Stornieren","arrayIndex":"16"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"L?schen","arrayIndex":"17"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Belastung","arrayIndex":"18"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Okay","arrayIndex":"19"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"setup","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"sparen","arrayIndex":"20"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Active","arrayIndex":"21"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"Add","arrayIndex":"22"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Cancel","arrayIndex":"23"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"Delete","arrayIndex":"24"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Load","arrayIndex":"25"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Okay","arrayIndex":"26"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"en-US","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"Save","arrayIndex":"27"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Activo","arrayIndex":"28"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"A?adir","arrayIndex":"29"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Cancelar","arrayIndex":"30"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"Borrar","arrayIndex":"31"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Carga","arrayIndex":"32"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Bueno","arrayIndex":"33"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"es-MX","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"Salvar","arrayIndex":"34"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Active","translatedCaption":"Aktiv","arrayIndex":"35"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Add","translatedCaption":"Hinzuf?gen","arrayIndex":"36"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Cancel","translatedCaption":"Stornieren","arrayIndex":"37"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Delete","translatedCaption":"L?schen","arrayIndex":"38"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Load","translatedCaption":"Belastung","arrayIndex":"39"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Okay","translatedCaption":"Okay","arrayIndex":"40"},{"siteName":"ct","pageName":"AppCommon","languageCode":"de-DE","englishCaption":"Save","translatedCaption":"sparen","arrayIndex":"41"}]
translator-page-data-import.component.ts:111 hasData is true`

I have tried many variations on this theme (i.e. using various change detection methods, using custom HTML tags, using Angular 2 ngSwitches & ngIfs, etc...) with no luck.
I have also tried directly access the HTML element to manipulate it in order to get it to display (i.e. blur() and focus(), etc...) with no luck.

It is possible that I am doing the Angular 2 Change Detection improperly, but there is no step by step example explaining exactly how & why each step is done that I have seen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Bill

Answer (score 0):

There might be other things but at first switch to using arrow functions to retain the scope of `this`

Change

```
 reader.onload = function(e) {
```

to

```
 reader.onload = (e) => {
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that out. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions. (I was on my phone when I wrote the answer and therefore omitted the link)

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out the answer to my issue. 
What I needed was a simple service from which to get my data. When the data changes, the view will update.

Here is a summary of what I did:

I added a simple service (TranslatorDataImportService) like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ITranslation } from './translation';

@Injectable()
export class TranslatorDataImportService {

    // the default state before translations are imported    
    noTranslations: ITranslation[] = [{
        "appName": "none",
        "pageName": "none",
        "cultureInfo": "none",    
        "target": "none",
        "value": "none"
    }];
    importedTranslations: ITranslation[];

    getImportedTranslatorData(newTranslations?: ITranslation[]) {
        if (newTranslations) {
        this.importedTranslations = newTranslations; 
        }
        else {
        this.importedTranslations = this.noTranslations;
        }

        return Promise.resolve(this.importedTranslations);
    }

}
```

I then modified my original type script file like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CanDeactivate, ComponentInstruction, Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { ITranslation } from './translation';
import { TranslatorDataImportService } from './translator-data-import.service';
import { TranslatorService } from './translator.service';

declare var Papa: any;

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/translator-page-data-import.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/translator-page-data-import.component.css',
                'app/assets/css/ngmes.css',
                'app/assets/css/toastr.min.css',
                'app/assets/css/ui-grid.min.css',
                'app/assets/css/ui-grid-override.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    selector:'table',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class TranslatorPageDataImportComponent implements OnInit {
    pageTitle: string = 'Import Application Data';
    hasData: boolean = false;
    errorMessage: string;
    importErrorMessage: string;

    translations: ITranslation[];

    constructor(private _translatorService: TranslatorService,
                private _translatorDataImportService: TranslatorDataImportService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    getTranslations(importedTranslations?: ITranslation[]): void {
        this._translatorDataImportService.getImportedTranslatorData(importedTranslations).then(translations => this.translations = translations);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('PAGE "' + this.pageTitle + '" WAS LOADED!!!');

        this.getTranslations();
    }

    saveTranslations(applicationName: string, importedData: ITranslation[]): void {
        this._translatorService.saveTranslations(applicationName, importedData)
            .subscribe(
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        if (this.errorMessage) {
            console.log("An error occured saving the data: " + this.errorMessage);
        }
        console.log("Save call complete");        
    }

    onChanges(changes){
        console.log("onChanges was fired");
    }

    importFile(evt) {
        this.hasData = true;
        console.log("hasData is " + this.hasData);

        let fileInput = evt.target;

        let file = fileInput.files[0];
        let textType = /text.*/;

        if (file.type.match(textType)) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
                let incomingCsvData: string = reader.result;
                // turn on if you need to inspect the raw CSV data
                // console.log("Incoming CSV Data" + incomingCsvData);

                let newJsonData: any = Papa.parse(incomingCsvData, {header: true});
                // turn on if you need to see the converted CSV data
                // console.log("Incoming CSV Data converted to JSON: ");
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(newJsonData));

                if (newJsonData.errors.length == 0 ) {
                    let importedTranslations: ITranslation[] = newJsonData.data;
                    let applicationName: string;
                    let passedTranslations: ITranslation[]= [];
                    let ignoredTranslations: ITranslation[]= [];
                    let index: number = 0;

                    console.log("Translations data was populated from file: ")
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(importedTranslations));
                    if (importedTranslations.length > 0) {
                        applicationName = importedTranslations[0].appName;
                        console.log("Application Name = " + applicationName);
                    }                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < importedTranslations.length; i++) {
                        importedTranslations[i].arrayIndex = i;
                    }

                    this.getTranslations(importedTranslations);
                    // this.saveTranslations(applicationName,importedTranslations);

                }
                else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < newJsonData.errors.length; i++) {
                        console.log("There were errors Importing the data.");
                        console.log("Error Type: " + newJsonData[i].errors.type);
                        console.log("Error Code: " + newJsonData[i].errors.code);
                        console.log("Error Message: " + newJsonData[i].errors.message);
                        console.log("Error Row: " + newJsonData[i].errors.row);
                    }
                }

            }

            reader.readAsText(file);    
        } else {
            console.log("File not supported!");
        }
    }     
}
```

Even though I am passing the data into the service that "gets the data, i.e.

```
this.getTranslations(importedTranslations);
```

from what I have read, this is apparently what Google wants you to do, instead of what I was doing.

Hope this helps someone else struggling with a similar issue.